# how to specify open id realm in openid4java 0.9.5

Tags: authentication, open-source, openid, openid-selector

my url @ development : http://192.168.0.1:8888/com.company.MyEntryPoint/MyEntrypoint.html
my url @ live env : http://www.example.com/com.company.MyEntryPoint/MyEntrypoint.html

I need users to authenticate using open id,
this is how i want my realm to be: 
*.company.MyEntryPoint

I wrote a simple code to specify realm:

```
AuthRequest authReq = 
    manager.authenticate(
        discovered,
        returnToUrl,
        "*.company.MyEntryPoint"
    );
```

it does not work.
Exception:

```
org.openid4java.message.MessageException: 0x301: Realm verification failed (2) for: *.company.MyEntryPoint
    at org.openid4java.message.AuthRequest.validate(AuthRequest.java:354)
    at org.openid4java.message.AuthRequest.createAuthRequest(AuthRequest.java:101)
    at org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.authenticate(ConsumerManager.java:1073)
```

Of all the combinations I tried, curiously, the following worked:

```
AuthRequest authReq = 
    manager.authenticate(
        discovered,
        returnToUrl,
        "http://localhost:8888/com.capgent.MyEntryPoint"
    );
```

This does not solves my issue but rather complicates it :)

According to [google](http://groups.google.com/group/google-federated-login-api/web/the-most-important-technical-issue-in-using-the-google-accounts-api?pli=1) and [open id spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0-12.html#realms) it should have worked

complete code snippet:

```
List discoveries = manager.discover(clientUrl);
DiscoveryInformation discovered = manager.associate(discoveries);
AuthRequest authReq = manager.authenticate(discovered, returnToUrl,"*.company.MyEntryPoint");
FetchRequest fetch = FetchRequest.createFetchRequest();
fetch.addAttribute("email", "http://schema.openid.net/contact/email", true);
fetch.addAttribute("country", "http://axschema.org/contact/country/home", true);
fetch.addAttribute("firstname", "http://axschema.org/namePerson/first", true);
fetch.addAttribute("lastname", "http://axschema.org/namePerson/last", true);
fetch.addAttribute("language", "http://axschema.org/pref/language", true);
authReq.addExtension(fetch);
String returnStr;
if (!discovered.isVersion2())
{
    returnStr = authReq.getDestinationUrl(true);
}
else
{
    returnStr = authReq.getDestinationUrl(false);
}
```

What am I doing wrong over here ?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/source/browse/trunk/src/org/openid4java/server/RealmVerifier.java?r=631#164 update, if (realmUrl.getAuthority().startsWith("*.")) realm = realm.replaceFirst("\\*\\.", "www.");

Answer (score 0):

returnStr = authReq.getDestinationUrl(false); **=>** returnStr = authReq.getDestinationUrl(**true**);